# Element is found but not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, web-scripting

I'm trying to find an element by it's id, click on it and download a file.

```
driver.get(url);
driver.implicitly_wait(60);
time.sleep(3)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_a1")))
href = element.get_attribute('href')
value = href.split('/')[-1]
print(value);
element.click(); # Error
```

Error
`element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (110, 1003)`

I've tried Xpath, and CSS path too. All give the same error. If I check for the visibility then it times out. But I can manually see that the element is visible

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'text of the link')]")))
```

At last, I tried this code.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_a1")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

But it gives error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
```

Comment: Without Url it is difficult to understand where is wrong. As an alternative try with `javascripts executor` to click on the element. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element ) `

Comment: url = "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/additional_surveillance_measure.aspx";

Comment: As stated in the above comment try with javascript executor it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While identified the element, page is still loading, may be the reason it is clicking on somewhere else.

Scroll down to the element and then wait for 1 to 2 seconds and then click.

It is working perfectly for me.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_a1")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view #scroll down to element
time.sleep(2) # wait for 2 seconds , 1 sec working as well
element.click()
```